# searching for main html file in cpanel live website

Tags: php, html, file, cpanel, cs-cart

i have a php website i.e a live store using cs-cart, in cPanel file manager i am searching for my main html file to make changes in my home page design but couldn't find it. can anyone help where the main html file located? it can be with the name of index.html or any other name but need the main file. please help

Answer (score 0):

At least for me it's in a public_html folder

Comment: i have seen the whole files in public_html folder but couldn't find it

Answer (score 0):

Normally it is under public_html but if you have added it as addon domain or subdomain then you will need to check the installation folder path.